# Add a new column with the diff of two values

Tags: sql, oracle, diff

SQL is goofy sometimes ain't it? Right now I want to take two values from different column and compare the difference. Ex:

```
ColA | ColB | New column
1    |  0   |  1
2    |  5   |  3
3    | 10   |  7
```

What should I do i order to create this RAD new column?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use computed/calculated column:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name
ADD new_column AS (ABS(ColB - ColA));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bbe6b01e286ae307093b76cdb03f8b0d)**

Comment: Will this assign the new column for new values? I can run this alteration, however if someone inserts a new row into this table, then that information won't be added. 

What would I add if I wanted to say, hav ea job that ran this every few days?

Ex:
instead of add column, we just want ti update a value for the column

Comment: @DrewL.Facchiano If someone add new row the info will be there. It is calculated on the fly, don't need to update it. The point is that when you fill ColB and ColA the difference will be calculated.

Comment: This sounds perfect, I am receiving this error

12:01:32  [ALTER - 0 row(s), 0.005 secs]  [Error Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

alter seems to not be valid

Comment: @DrewL.Facchiano Please post `SELECT * FROM v$version;`

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @DrewL.Facchiano Does your column contain spaces? If yes, enclose it with `"`

Comment: @DrewL.Facchiano Just remove `COLUMN` keyword

Comment: Thanks @Lad20205 you are a hero <3

Comment: There used to be a pick answer section. Have they moved it?

Comment: @Lad20205 thats the one!

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need a new column? Perhaps you just want access to this value in a select statement?

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ABS(ColA - ColB) AS [New column]
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this...

```
select ColA, ColB, ABS(ColA-ColB) as 'New column' from table
```